# What happens when invoke Object.defineProperty for a function's prototype?

Tags: javascript, get, prototype, getter, defineproperty

```
var Foo = function(){};

Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype,'x',{
    get(){
        return 3;
    }
});

var foo = new Foo();

console.dir(foo);
```

The result I am looking for should be

```
Foo {
    __proto__:{
        constructor: ƒ (),
        x: 3,
        __proto__: Object
    }
}
```

But the real result is

```
Foo {
    x: 3,
    __proto__:{
        constructor: ƒ (),
        x: 3,
        __proto__: Object
    }
}
```

Why is the x attribute already appearing at the outermost layer?

Comment: Looks like `console.dir` is confused. This is a bug. `x` is not an own property of `foo`.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=915867

Comment: awesome.........!

Answer (score -2):

## What Happened (Step-by-step)

```
var Foo = function(){};
```

A new function is defined, named - Foo. If we use `console.dir(Foo)` we will see that `Foo` has 2 special members `prototype` and `__proto__`

```
Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype,'x',{
    get(){
        return 3;
    }
});
```

The prototype of Foo is updated. About `defineProperty` (From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)):

> The static method Object.defineProperty() defines a new property
> directly on an object, or modifies an existing property on an object,
> and returns the object.

So the `prototype` object is now modified with a new member named `x`. The `prototype` here acts as a c'tor and will "kick-off" when a new instance of `Foo` will be created

```
var foo = new Foo();
```

A new instance of Foo is created. the c'tor call is using Foo prototype and `x` getter is applied

## Alternatives

Extending `Foo prototype`, thus making sure it will effect only objects created from `Foo` (as a class)

```
Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, 'x',
{
    get: () => 3
}); 

console.dir(new Foo().x) // will show 3
console.dir(Foo.x) // undefined - protorype is for class objects
```

Or extending `Foo __proto__`, thus updating `Foo` as a function and while not affecting objectes created from it

```
Object.defineProperty(Foo.__proto__, 'x',
{
    get: () => 3
}); 

console.dir(new Foo().x) // undefined - x is not a member of Foo
console.dir(Foo.x) // 3
```

**Bonus:** a very good [article](https://hackernoon.com/understand-nodejs-javascript-object-inheritance-proto-prototype-class-9bd951700b29) about JS prototypes and why this is happening

## Original Answer

This is happening because in JS `function` is a way to declare BOTH functions and classes!

So your `Foo` function can be also used as a class

```
var Foo = function(){};
Foo(); // call Foo as a function
var obj = new Foo(); // initiate an instance from class Foo
```

Because you are using `Foo.prototype` object <s>(as a function)</s> and then you create a new instance from your `Foo` class you guarantee that:

1. Your function prototype will be modified with your new getter
2. Every new object (that inherits) from your class will also use your new getter (in object level)

I really think that your code should be something like this instead:

```
function Foo ()
{
    Object.defineProperty(this,'x',{
       get(){
           return 3;
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: "*you are using `Foo.prototype` object (as a function)*" - no, he doesn't? And that's not even possible, as `Foo.prototype` is not a function!

Comment: `Foo.__proto__` is just `Function.prototype`. As you said, adding properties to will not affect objects constructed from Foo, but you seem to have missed that it will affect every single function. After you extend `Foo.__proto__` try `console.log(function(){}.x);`